# Creating a distribution zip file with Spring Boot and Gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot (1.0.0.RELASE) and I want to create a distribution zip file containing the following:

1. The spring boot one-jar created when running "gradle build" (located in build/libs/x.jar)
2. A config folder with some files that are located in src/dist/config

Preferable I would like this zip file to be created when running "gradle build" (but another task is fine if this is hard to achieve). Is there nice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

```
task zip(type: Zip, dependsOn: bootRepackage) {
    from('build/libs') {
        include '*.jar'
    }
    from 'conf'
}

build.dependsOn(zip)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar to what Dave Syer suggested:

```
task zip(type: Zip, dependsOn: bootRepackage) {
  def fileName = "${jar.baseName}-${jar.version}"
  from projectDir
  include "script.sh"
  from file("$buildDir/libs")
  include "${fileName}.jar"
  from file('src/dist')
  include "config/application.yml"
  archiveName "${fileName}.zip"
}

build.dependsOn(zip)
```

Any improvement suggestions are welcome.

Comment: my task include all jar,but I want only include bootrepack's one jar,do you resolve this?

Comment: In spring boot 2.1.3 use `dependsOn: bootJar` instead of `bootRepackage`.